# Possible for "expect" to only answer some questions?

Tags: linux, bash, expect

The problem with this script is that if there are any `yum` updates, then it still exits.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn su -c "yum update"
expect "Password: "
send "secret\n"
expect eof
exit
```

I would like to be able to answer yes or no in that situation.

**Question**

Is it possible to just have `except` to answer the password question, and then let the rest be interactive?

Comment: unrelated to `expect`, but in this case just use `yum -y update`, where `-y` will make it answer _yes_ to all questions. If you want to answer _no_ in some cases, it will not work for you.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath that should be an answer.  I didn't know about "interact" until about a month ago, and it is really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn su -c "yum update"
expect "Password: "
send "secret\n"
interact
exit
```